# SQL for hotel room availability in ASP c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have these three tables:
[image]

With this SELECT statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.roomId,rt.roomTypeName,rt.roomTypeDesc,rt.roomTypePrice
FROM Room r left join RoomType rt 
    on r.roomTypeId=rt.roomTypeId 
WHERE roomStatus='Online' 
     AND NOT EXISTS(
         SELECT 1 FROM Reservation b WHERE b.roomId = r.roomId 
           AND ('7/11/2015' BETWEEN b.checkInDate
           AND b.checkOutDate OR '8/11/2015' BETWEEN b.checkInDate 
           AND b.checkOutDate OR ('7/11/2015'<= b.checkInDate AND '8/11/2015' >= b.checkOutDate)))
order by rt.roomTypePrice
```

I get this result

[image]

How can I count the number of available rooms of each room type, so that I can use a drop down list in [RESULT] to allow user select the quantity that they want? (Similiar as the website Agoda.com.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT rt.roomTypeName, count(rt.roomTypeName)
    FROM Room r left join RoomType rt 
    on r.roomTypeId=rt.roomTypeId 
    WHERE roomStatus='Online' 
         AND NOT EXISTS(
             SELECT 1 FROM Reservation b WHERE b.roomId = r.roomId 
             AND ('7/11/2015' BETWEEN b.checkInDate
             AND b.checkOutDate OR '8/11/2015' BETWEEN b.checkInDate 
             AND b.checkOutDate OR ('7/11/2015'<= b.checkInDate AND '8/11/2015' >= b.checkOutDate)))
    GROUP BY rt.roomTypeName
```

More on `GROUP BY`:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

This basically says 'give me every `roomTypeName` in column 1 and a count of all records where the roomTypeName is not null in column 2'

That's not yet distinct, but then the use of `GROUP BY` ensures the results set is 'rolled up' into distinct `roomTypeName` values, thus the count then applies to the count of occurrences of records with that `roomTypeName` value.

Comment: Please don't link to W3Schools as it is not a reliable source of information. Link to the source of information instead, like this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

Comment: @atornblad - giving the level at which this question is being asked, I find w3c schools a lot more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic for determining room availability is overly complicated.  A room is not available for a period if the period start is less than some reservation's end date and the period end is after that reservation's start date:

```
SELECT rt.roomTypeName, COUNT(*)
FROM Room r left join
     RoomType rt 
     on r.roomTypeId = rt.roomTypeId 
WHERE roomStatus = 'Online' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM Reservation b
                  WHERE b.roomId = r.roomId AND
                        '2015-11-07' < b.checkoutDate AND
                        '2015-11-08' >= b.checkinDate
                 )
GROUP BY rt.roomTypeName;
```

The use of `BETWEEN` for overlap logic indicates an overly complicated query at the minimum, and a potential logic error (in most cases).

NOTE:  I changed the dates to ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD format.  I assume they are in November.